# Is there a way to specify which pivot item to navigate to in a pivot page?

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, pivot

I know how to navigate from one pivot item to another, within the pivot page, but what if the navigation is initiated from another page entirely?

UPDATE:

Here is the solution I used, based on the answer from Matt Lacey:

From button click event on MainPage:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string parameter = "myPivotItem1";
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/MyPivotPage.xaml?parameter={0}", parameter), UriKind.Relative)); 
        }
```

Overrode OnNavigatedTo for the pivot page, and extracted the querystring:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            string newparameter = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];
            if (newparameter.Equals("myPivotItem1"))
            {
                myPivotControl.SelectedItem = myPivotItem1;
            }
            else if (newparameter.Equals("myPivotItem2"))
            {
                myPivotControl.SelectedItem = myPivotItem2;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `SelectedIndex` to the index of the item you want.

Be careful of the delayed loading of item though.

**Update:**
On the first page, pass an indicator of which pivotItem to display in the querystring** of the page you are navigating to.
In the OnNavigatedTo event on the page, containing the pivot, create a handler for the Loaded event of the Pivot and use that to set the SelectedIndex.

** Other ways of doing this are available.

Comment: Thank you, googled the term querystring and found this in depth explanation of wp7 navigation and concepts: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Navigation-in-depth--Navigation-Framework

Comment: you mention that there are different ways of passing an indicator of the pivot item you wish to navigate to, are you referring to the use of isolatedstorage, databases, and other global storage, that would allow you to set a value accessible across the application?

Comment: @videre  in terms of passing data between pages I'd use the querystring or a global viewmodel. IsolatedStorage or databases would be overkill. Use of QueryString or ViewModel would depend on what's appropriate for the app.